# How to resize image in angular 2 before uploading it to server?

Tags: angular

I want to resize image with size of 74 x 74, I am using ng2-uploader directive to upload image.
If there is any other directive I can use to achieve my requirement please suggest me.
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [ng2-imageupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-imageupload). It enables you to automagically resize the image before it gets uploaded.

Just modify your template and add a few directives to the input field and add the hidden image tag for the image upload:

```html
<img [src]="src" [hidden]="!src">
<input type="file" imageUpload (imageSelected)="selected($event)" [resizeOptions]="resizeOptions">
```

In your component you add the resize options and the `selected` method:

```ts
src: string = "";
resizeOptions: ResizeOptions = {
    resizeMaxHeight: 74,
    resizeMaxWidth: 74
};

selected(imageResult: ImageResult) {
    this.src = imageResult.resized 
      && imageResult.resized.dataURL
      || imageResult.dataURL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Does it provide drag & drop feature?

Comment: No, but you can use it with your `ng2-uploader` which does provide drag and drop if I remember correctly.

Comment: Don't you know if it's possible for more than one image? ..I mean I've got an input field with possibility to choose multiple images, so I'm wondering what to use to resize and reduce image size.

Comment: The directive name "image-upload" has changed to "imageUpload". I had an error when using the former. Be advised ;)

Comment: What if we user want to resize it-self? as it cropped image with area resizer

Answer (score 6):

Yes we can use `ng2-img-cropper` for croping the image before uploading also you can customize dimension according to your requirement, you just have to install the package named as ng2-img-cropper from the node
using

> npm install ng2-img-cropper --save

than just use the component by importing

`import {ImageCropperComponent, CropperSettings, Bounds} from 'ng2-img-`cropper';

<kbd>[Working plunker here](https://embed.plnkr.co/V91mKCNkBQZB5QO2MUP4/)</kbd>
For more info see here,

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-img-cropper

Comment: Its image cropper it crop the image not resize it

Answer (score 0):

I used `npm i ngx-image-compress` and it works great.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-compress